# npm install bcrypt - no errors but a whole raft of warnings on windows 7

Tags: node.js, bcrypt, npm-install

OK, so all the brcypt issues on here seem to be node-gyp related, but after playing with bcrypt for a while I finally got it installing with no errors and node-gyp seems happy, but I am still getting quite a few warnings.  It's obviously related to visual studio but I can't find anything about these specifically.

I'm on windows 7 x64 ultimate and have:

- visual studio 2012 utlimate
- visual studio 2013 ultimate
- python 0.2.7.10
- windows 7 x64 sdk with all updates
- Win64OpenSSL-1_0_lt

I'm getting the following warnings:

```
D:\WebstormProjects\authapp>npm install --save bcrypt
npm WARN package.json authapp@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json authapp@1.0.0 No README data

bcrypt@0.8.6 install D:\WebstormProjects\authapp\node_modules\bcrypt
node-gyp rebuild


D:\WebstormProjects\authapp\node_modules\bcrypt>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\n
odejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node
"" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  blowfish.cc
  bcrypt.cc
  bcrypt_node.cc
**..\src\bcrypt.cc(232): warning C4267: '=' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned char', possible loss of d
ata [D:\WebstormProjects\authapp\node_modules\bcrypt\build\bcrypt_lib.vcxproj]
..\src\bcrypt_node.cc(76): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'ssize_t' to 'unsigned char', possib
le loss of data [D:\WebstormProjects\authapp\node_modules\bcrypt\build\bcrypt_lib.vcxproj]
..\src\bcrypt_node.cc(229): warning C4267: 'initializing' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible los
s of data [D:\WebstormProjects\authapp\node_modules\bcrypt\build\bcrypt_lib.vcxproj]
..\src\bcrypt_node.cc(230): warning C4267: 'initializing' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible los
s of data [D:\WebstormProjects\authapp\node_modules\bcrypt\build\bcrypt_lib.vcxproj]**
  win_delay_load_hook.c
     Creating library D:\WebstormProjects\authapp\node_modules\bcrypt\build\Release\bcrypt_lib.lib and obje
  ct D:\WebstormProjects\authapp\node_modules\bcrypt\build\Release\bcrypt_lib.exp
  Generating code
  Finished generating code
  bcrypt_lib.vcxproj -> D:\WebstormProjects\authapp\node_modules\bcrypt\build\Release\\bcrypt_lib.node
bcrypt@0.8.6 node_modules\bcrypt
├── bindings@1.2.1
└── nan@2.2.1
```

Does anyone have any ideas what's gone wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Windows, I recommend you use [Bcrypt-NodeJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt-nodejs) to avoid these errors if possible. You'll get about the same functionality, as far as I can tell.